# using bootstrap-fileinput in angular app, css isn't working

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building an app using the mean stack and bootstrap to style the web pages. On one of the forms the user needs to upload an image, so I decided to add the [bootstrap-fileinput](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input) plugin to do that. After I added the file input to the form it works fine, but it's not styled in anyway. I was expecting it to look just like the examples they have on the website.

My directory structure, with some parts removed to condense it:

```
.
├── app/
├── bower.json
├── config/
│   └── db.js
├── node_modules/
├── package.json
├── public/
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── js/
│   │   ├── app.js
│   │   ├── appRoutes.js
│   │   ├── controllers/
│   │   │   └── MainController.js
│   │   └── services/
│   ├── libs/
│   │   ├── angular/
│   │   ├── angular-bootstrap/
│   │   ├── angular-route/
│   │   ├── bootstrap/
│   │   ├── bootstrap-fileinput/
│   │   ├── jquery/
│   │   └── mobile-angular-ui/
│   └── views/
│       ├── main.html
├── README.md
└── server.js
```

**index.html**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My App</title>
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/bootstrap-fileinput/css/fileinput.min.css">
    <!-- JS -->
    <script src="libs/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/jquery/src/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/bootstrap-fileinput/js/fileinput.min.js"></script>

    <!-- ANGULAR CUSTOM -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/appRoutes.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/MainController.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="my_app">
<div class="container">

    <!-- HEADER -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Welcome to the App!</a>
    </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- ANGULAR DYNAMIC CONTENT -->
    <div ng-view></div>

</div>
</body>
```

And the relevant code from the form, which was an angular view:

**view.html**

```
<div class="container">
<h1>Test form</h1><br>
<form>
<div>
    <label class="control-label">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="newItem.name">
</div>
<div>
    <label class="control-label">Description:</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="newItem.description">
</div>
<div>
    <label class="control-label">Select File</label>
    <input id="input-1" type="file" class="file">
</div>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Do you see anything wrong here? When I inspected the page in my browser it looks like the fileinput style is never being applied to the input at all, instead of being overwritten by the bootstrap css or something.

Let me know if the Javascript would be useful as well.

Comment: It's hard to diagnose with the code you have posted.  Could you create a plunker or jsfiddle that shows the problem?

Comment: I just spent the last 20 minutes or so trying to get it to work in plunker or jsfiddle and I couldn't even get the views to load unfortunately. I'm pretty new to the javascript world and haven't had to use either before. Would it help if I edited my post to add more of my code? Maybe the directory structure?

Comment: Yes, whatever you can post would help diagnosing.